# PowerBI slicer to select "multiple" columns in a table to show multiple lines in a Line Chart?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded

I've been able to make a slicer that selects one single item and shows it in a line chart.

What I'd really like, is to be able to select multiple items in the slicer, and not just a single one (as below), to be able to show multiple lines in the line chart.

So it's basically like turning various columns on/off in a table.

Wanted behavior

1. Single or multiple selections
2. Select date range
3. Show results for selection(s) AND date range
4. Show SUM() for selection(s) AND date range

You can see the *live* version [here](https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiN2FkYTFlZjItNTQwZi00YmZkLTlkMmUtNWNjYjcxMTQwOTFhIiwidCI6ImUxNTkwMzRhLTc5ODQtNDQ2ZS1iODM0LWUxZTM3ZDE2NzY3OSJ9&pageName=ReportSection6d5458d7e2738b773e52)

[image]

This is the code I use for the above example (3)

[image]

And the code for (4)

[image]

This data is imported automatically from a JSON web service (government health data)

[image]

I have many ages groups for a given date, each with a count for that day.

[image]

The columns are structured that way because I also use those values in **pie charts** on other pages.

[image]

Now. I did try to unpivot the data and use it as in the example provided by [@joao-leal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1309027/joao-leal)

[image]

However, this breaks the counter (4) mentioned at the very beginning.

[image]

Because apparently when you select 2 or more elements in the slicer, it defaults to the (isBlank) switch ...which will mess up the calculations, since not based on the selected values anymore (but the line chart works)

[image]

Any idea how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: PS. I've been using PowerBI for a whopping 4 days now, so be easy on me ;-)

Comment: Probably is a big change now, but I would definitely pivot the hell out of those tables, and combine them all into a single one with 4 columns  "Date", "Age", "Type", "Count".

Comment: Yes, I've been playing with your first answer, and it comes pretty close to what I need. I've done SQL and frontend with json, so used what I was most familiar with. The biggest challenge seems to be learning this dax with zero debug or dump capabilities 

Comment: The best dax is where you need little or no dax at all :D

Answer (score 2):

So the way I'd do it would be to create a table with your slicer info:

[image]

And then a measure that took into account the selected slicer and show the number of cases:

```
TotalCases = 
VAR minAge = SELECTEDVALUE(Slicer[MinAge])
VAR maxAge = SELECTEDVALUE(Slicer[MaxAge])
RETURN IF(ISBLANK(minAge), 
    COUNTROWS('Cases'), 
    CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Cases'), 'Cases'[NewAge] >= minAge && 'Cases'[NewAge] <= maxAge))
```

And then add the slicer to the chart legend:

[image]

With the following result

[image]

Edit: this is the model I've used, you can connect the slicer to the data table, but if it's disconnected it let's you have a "tous" category with a min age of 0 and max of 999, similar to what you currently have.

[image]

Comment: Just tried your solution by unpivoting my tables, but seems to introduce other bugs and caveats. I updated the question with more images and explanations. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Adding another answer because it is a bit different to my original one, given your model.
Start with a table with your slicer values:

[image]

Then you can create a measure that looks at the selected value and picks the correct columns:

```
TotalDeceePerSlicer = 
    VAR selectedSlicer = SELECTEDVALUE('Slicer'[Label]) 
    RETURN SWITCH(selectedSlicer, 
        "0-10", SUM('Deces (Jour)'[0-10]), 
        "11-20", SUM('Deces (Jour)'[11-20]), 
        "21-30", SUM('Deces (Jour)'[21-30]), 
        "31+", SUM('Deces (Jour)'[31+])))
```

But this doesn't solve the places where you are just showing a total and where you still want to take the slicer selection into account. But you can create a measure that uses the above one:

```
SUMX(
    SUMMARIZE(Slicer, 
    Slicer[Label],
    "cases", [TotalDeceePerSlicer]), 
    [cases])
```

This should let you do what you want, you just need to be careful with the "Tous" category, cause it is almost a different level than others and you don't want to combine it with the different age gaps at the same time.

Note:
You would benefit a lot into having the model done right: 1 table with the measures with 4 columns:

```
Date 
Type = {Vaccination 1 dose, Vaccination 2 dose, Hospitalization, Deces...}
Age = {0-9 and, 10-19 ans, ...} //(and I'd also exclude the Tous)
Value
```

It would make your life a lot easier in building the visualisations you have.

Comment: Cool, will have a closer look at all that as soon as I can. Gonna be on vacation for a few days, but will update my progress and mark something as the answer with some explanations as soon as I get it working. Thanks for the new information 

Comment: Actually all the results were in 3 columns at the start. I pivoted them out of habit of using data that way. Also the deaths table was using cumulative data originally, so i made a reference with two indexes and then reverse engineered the results to have the count per day  [index - index-(n-1)]. Not sure if I'll be able to reproduce that one by going back to 3-4 columns ...but will eventually figure it out ^^

Comment: Another caveat is that with all the datasets, there are 3 unrelated age groups, with disparate intervals. I was able to add a few measures to make them more similar and create some aggregate categories like ≤49yo & ≥50yo. Hopefully in the end I'll have something homogeneous and not too complicated, as I'm sharing the project openly for others to use if they like  Thanks again 

Comment: Yeah, but you can then expand that however you want. Ideally you'd want the Age, cause that would give you the most flexibility and the ability to then have a "Age Grouping" table with the different groupings that you'd want to offer. Having it like that you don't have to mess up with complex formulas/calculations, cause the age group is just a normal filter on a column and the totals get sliced correctly. Of course there are many ways to achieve the same result... :)